# Cancel button not closing popup window in app or some web browsers

Tags: html, popup, popupwindow, cancel-button

I have a popup window which has a cancel button. I want the window to close on the click of the button. The window.close() function performs the task in Chrome, but not on other browsers. Or even app. I want the popup to close on web and app both. Please help.

`<button onclick="window.close()" class="cancel">CANCEL</button>`

Comment: Is the window opened by Javascript? Are you getting any errors in browser console when you click close? Note that you won't be able to close the window if it is not opened by Javascript.

Comment: I am getting the error "Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script." how to work around this ??

Comment: I thought so. There is no workaround to that. It is implemented by browsers to enhance security: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close

Comment: Can I open the same window using a window.open() method at the top of the code? And then make this close script run?

Comment: Yes, I've just posted an answer explaining that as well.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, the browser might prevent you from closing a window through `window.close()` if said window was not opened by Javascript in the first place (i.e. `window.open()`). <sup>(1)</sup>

You can confirm this by checking the browser console, which reports the following error:

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

The solution to such problem would be to ensure that said window is opened through `window.open()`.

---

<sub>(1) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close</sub>